# HTML Form to Facebook inbox

Tags: facebook, forms, message, contacts, inbox

I have had a good look around and have found no real solid answer, is it possible to have a contact form on a website send to facebooks inbox?

Any kind of help/answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible.